# My LinkedList Print Function is not working

Tags: c++

I've done a linked list in Java, I am trying to convert the code to C++ because my next class is going to solely going to use C++. Here's my code below. Can you give it a look see. I've drew diagrams and stuff and it makes sense to me but doesn't seem to work don't. Have no clue.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Node{
        public:
          int data;
          Node* next;

    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
    }
 };

   class LinkedList{
       private:
           Node* n;
           Node* t;
           Node* Header = NULL;
           int length = 0;
       public:
           void append(int d){
               if (Header == NULL){
                  n = new Node(d);
                  Header = n;
                  t = n;
                  length++;
               }
               else{
                  n = new Node(d);
                  t->next = n;
                  t = n;
                  length++;
               }
        }

void printList(){
    if (Header == NULL){
        cout << "Nothing to print" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node* n = Header;
    while (n != NULL){
        cout << n->data + " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
}



 };

   int main(){
        LinkedList a;
        a.append(1);
        a.append(2);
        a.append(3);
        a.printList();
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    }
```

Comment: What *specifically* are you having trouble with?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about free debugging/mentoring/tuition, not entries into our programming questions respository.

Comment: Question was about the print of the linkedlist It has been answered though.

Comment: As the answer stated, C++ is not Java.  You are allocating memory using `new`, but nowhere do you issue a single `delete` call to deallocate the memory.  Therefore your LinkedList is seriously flawed due to it leaking memory.

Comment: So I can create delete function within the linkedlist Class and goes through each Node and delete them as its going. I would need some sort of temp pointer to the next because when I delete the node i am going to lose the pointer. Now all i need to know is the delete syntax lol. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cout << n->data + " ";
```

to

```
cout << n->data << " ";
```

C++ is not like Java, you cannot append a C-style string to an int.